# active record finding record based on date params passed in url

Tags: sql, date, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am simply trying to find matching record using params passed in url ( date )  , using active record " where " clause  .

my problem is that passed date in url dont match with created_At dates  so its returning zero records but all the created date is same as param date .
 in console i am seeing this kind of weird problem

```
>> r.created_at
=> Mon, 03 Mar 2014 00:47:46 IST +05:30

>> params[:date]
=> "03/03/2014"

>> params[:date].to_date
=> Mon, 03 Mar 2014

>> r.created_at === params[:date].to_date
=> false
```

it returning me " 0 " records , but all the records are even created on given date only .
In my controller :

```
Something.where("created_at = ?" , params[:date].to_date )
```

Comment: instead of `.where("created_at = ?" , params[:date].to_date )`

using symbols worked

`.where( :created_at == params[:date].to_date )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your params[:date] to the appropriate date format OR created_at date to the appropriate format using `strftime` method.

```
created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") == params[:date]
```

You can also apply `to_date` method to both variables:

```
created_at.to_date == params[:date].to_date
```

Comment: i want to convert params date to match with created_that i used .to_date method but it doesnt work let me try using strftime

Comment: `.where( :created_at == params[:date].to_date )`

that worked